# python: Update MongoDB document

Tags: python, mongodb

I want to update a MongoDB document without searching for it. All the methods I've found, like `updateOne()` for example, first search for the document and then update it. But I already have the document.

```
for newDocument in scrape:
    query = { "title": newDocument["title"] }
    oldDocument = col.find_one(query)
    if oldDocument:
        # Check if any changes
        # If has changes -> update document IF APPROVED BY USER
        print("has document")
    else:
        col.insert_one(newDocument)
        print("added")
```

I scan something to get a list of new dictionary objects. I then loop through these objects to check if they exists in my database. If not, I add it. If it does, I check for any changes and ask the user if they should be approved (not shown).

Is there a method to update the document without also querying for it? Because I already did the query and have the reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no other choice than making an [update](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) query